# Connectable Bluetooth LE advertisement with manufacturer specific data on Windows 10

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

By using the GattServiceProvider class I can create an advertisement that advertises a BLE service + characteristic. This advertisement is connectable.

With the BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher class I can create an advertisement containing manufacturer specific data, but this advertisement is not connectable.

Has any of you found a way to create an connectable BLE advertisement with manufacturer specific data on Windows 10?

Comment: Service data appears in the advertisement. Could you use ServiceData instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattserviceprovideradvertisingparameters.servicedata?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_GenericAttributeProfile_GattServiceProviderAdvertisingParameters_ServiceData

Comment: @ukBaz - that seems like a good suggestion, but I cannot get it to work. I add a single byte to GattServiceProviderAdvertisingParameters.ServiceData, this way: byte[] data = new byte[] { 0xA4 };
AdvertisementParameters.ServiceData = data.AsBuffer(); but the advertising data does not change. It's exactly like before. I guess I do something wrong. Or there is no space for that extra byte.

Comment: Does this example help? https://github.com/ProH4Ck/treadmill-bridge/blob/98e683e2380178319972af522d9251f44350a448/src/TreadmillBridge/Services/VirtualTreadmill/VirtualTreadmillService.cs#L90

Comment: @ukBaz: I copied the setup of advParameters and used it in the StartAdvertising command. But it does not change anything. I also tried copying the setup and use of CreateCharacteristicAsync, but again no changes in what I can see with nrRF Connect (the mobile app I use to discover devices). Before the ServiceData property of GattServiceProviderAdvertisingParameters became visible I had to change the reference to Windows.winmd from version 10.0.17134.0 to 10.0.18362.0. I am still on Windows 10 build 18363 could that be the problem?